# Random number with equal total

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have 4 number

```
a,b,c,d : integers
```

i need to have a random number between 2-7 assigned to each one but the total of all four numbers has to be 22

how can i do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: well i can do it , but its super long.  i get a random number subtract it from 22. get another randome number and subtract it from 22. then devide that number by 2 assign it to C and then subtract c from 22 and that value is D...its really long and has to be a better way....i guess more so a formula for doing this?  not the best at math formulas

Comment: @tlama dam I feel asleep. Before seeing your code.

Comment: Also looks good.  So much math I would have to test cause calculators  destroyed my simple math

Comment: @TLama Please undelete your answer. I'm going to extend mine to include some distributional comparisons of the various candidates.

Comment: @David, I feel stupid about my post since I don't know anything about algorithms you're discussing here. I just feel (and I'm almost sure) the code I've posted could work, nothing more. And for those who wants to see it, [`it's here`](http://pastebin.com/ypRXPRMi). Though I'd rather keep that post deleted.

Comment: @TLama OK. I think your idea is sound though. I'm going to attempt to see if you have an implementation error because I feel the algo is sound.

Comment: @TLama I found the fault in your code, the reason why it was not generating certain valid combinations. RandomRange used an open closed interval, `AFrom <= Value < ATo`. The algo is still not uniform though. All very interesting. At least to me!!  ;-)

Comment: @David, thanks for fixing that! Initially I've used my own `RandomRange` function which I used in the correct range. Thijs then pointed out the existing `RandomRange` function in comment and so I just replaced all the calls of my own function with `RandomRange` without thinking of it anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I'm going to make it clear that as stated the question does not uniquely define the problem. You ask for random sampling, but do not specify the desired distribution of the samples.

It's a common abuse of mathematical terminology to say *random* when you actually mean *uniformly distributed*. So I'm going to assume that's what you mean. Specifically that you want all possible distinct sets of 4 numbers to have equal probability of selection. The simplest and most efficient way to achieve this is as follows:

- Enumerate all such possible sets of 4 numbers.
- Count these sets of numbers, say N.
- To sample, choose random number, i say, from uniform distribution in range 0 to N-1.
- Return the i-th set of 4 numbers.

The list of possible distinct sets is small. Off the top of my head I'd guess there are around 50 candidates.

Generating the list of candidates is quite simple. Just run three nested for loops from 2 to 7. This gives you combinations of the first three numbers. Add them up, subtract from 22 and check if the final number is in range.

---

Since you seem to like to see code, here's a simple demonstration:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Math,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TValue = record
    a, b, c, d: Integer;
    procedure Write;
  end;

procedure TValue.Write;
begin
  Writeln(a, ' ', b, ' ', c, ' ', d);
end;

var
  Combinations: TArray<TValue>;

procedure InitialiseCombinations;
var
  a, b, c, d: Integer;
  Value: TValue;
  List: TList<TValue>;
begin
  List := TList<TValue>.Create;
  try
    for a := 2 to 7 do
      for b := 2 to 7 do
        for c := 2 to 7 do
        begin
          d := 22 - a - b - c;
          if InRange(d, 2, 7) then
          begin
            Value.a := a;
            Value.b := b;
            Value.c := c;
            Value.d := d;
            List.Add(Value);
          end;
        end;
    Combinations := List.ToArray;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetSample: TValue;
begin
  Result := Combinations[Random(Length(Combinations))];
end;

var
  i: Integer;

begin
  Randomize;
  InitialiseCombinations;
  for i := 1 to 25 do
    GetSample.Write;
  Readln;
end.
```

---

It's clear from inspection that this algorithm samples from the available values uniformly.

But what about the other proposed algorithms. We can perform a crude heuristic test by sampling repeatedly and counting how many times each possible sample is produced. Here it is:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Math,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TValue = record
    a, b, c, d: Integer;
    procedure Write;
    class operator Equal(const lhs, rhs: TValue): Boolean;
  end;

procedure TValue.Write;
begin
  Writeln(a, ' ', b, ' ', c, ' ', d);
end;

class operator TValue.Equal(const lhs, rhs: TValue): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (lhs.a=rhs.a) and (lhs.b=rhs.b) and (lhs.c=rhs.c) and (lhs.d=rhs.d);
end;

var
  Combinations: TArray<TValue>;

procedure InitialiseCombinations;
var
  a, b, c, d: Integer;
  Value: TValue;
  List: TList<TValue>;
begin
  List := TList<TValue>.Create;
  try
    for a := 2 to 7 do
      for b := 2 to 7 do
        for c := 2 to 7 do
        begin
          d := 22 - a - b - c;
          if InRange(d, 2, 7) then
          begin
            Value.a := a;
            Value.b := b;
            Value.c := c;
            Value.d := d;
            List.Add(Value);
          end;
        end;
    Combinations := List.ToArray;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetSampleHeffernan: TValue;
begin
  Result := Combinations[Random(Length(Combinations))];
end;

function GetSampleVanDien: TValue;
const
  TOTAL = 22;
  VALUE_COUNT = 4;
  MIN_VALUE = 2;
  MAX_VALUE = 7;
var
  Values: array[0..VALUE_COUNT-1] of Integer;
  Shortage: Integer;
  Candidates: TList<Integer>;
  ValueIndex: Integer;
  CandidateIndex: Integer;
begin
  Assert(VALUE_COUNT * MAX_VALUE >= TOTAL, 'Total can never be reached!');
  Assert(VALUE_COUNT * MIN_VALUE <= TOTAL, 'Total is always exceeded!');
  Randomize;
  Candidates := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    for ValueIndex := 0 to VALUE_COUNT-1 do
    begin
      Values[ValueIndex] := MIN_VALUE;
      Candidates.Add(ValueIndex);
    end;
    Shortage := TOTAL - VALUE_COUNT * MIN_VALUE;
    while Shortage > 0 do
    begin
      CandidateIndex := Random(Candidates.Count);
      ValueIndex := Candidates[CandidateIndex];
      Values[ValueIndex] := Values[ValueIndex] + 1;
      if Values[ValueIndex] = MAX_VALUE then
        Candidates.Remove(CandidateIndex);
      Shortage := Shortage - 1;
    end;
  finally
    Candidates.Free;
  end;

  Result.a := Values[0];
  Result.b := Values[1];
  Result.c := Values[2];
  Result.d := Values[3];
end;

function GetSampleLama: TValue;
type
  TRandomValues = array[1..4] of Integer;
var
  IntSum: Integer;
  Values: TRandomValues;
begin
  // initialize a helper variable for calculating sum of the generated numbers
  IntSum := 0;
  // in the first step just generate a number in the range of 2 to 7 and store
  // it to the first integer element
  Values[1] := RandomRange(2, 7);
  // and increment the sum value
  IntSum := IntSum + Values[1];
  // as the next step we need to generate number, but here we need also say in
  // which range by the following rules to ensure we ever reach 22 (consider, if
  // the 1st number was e.g. 3, then you can't generate the second number smaller
  // than 5 because then even if the next two numbers would be max, you would get
  // e.g. only 3 + 4 + 7 + 7 = 21, so just use this rule:
  // Values[1] Values[2]
  //        2      6..7
  //        3      5..7
  //        4      4..7
  //        5      3..7
  //     6..7      2..7
  Values[2] := RandomRange(Max(2, 8 - Values[1]), 7);
  // and increment the sum value
  IntSum := IntSum + Values[2];
  // if the third step we need to generate a value in the range of 15 to 20 since
  // the fourth number can be still in the range of 2 to 7 which means that the sum
  // after this step must be from 22-7 to 22-2 which is 15 to 20, so let's generate
  // a number which will fit into this sum
  Values[3] := RandomRange(Max(2, Min(7, 15 - IntSum)), Max(2, Min(7, 20 - IntSum)));
  // and for the last number let's just take 22 and subtract the sum of all previous
  // numbers
  Values[4] := 22 - (IntSum + Values[3]);

  Result.a := Values[1];
  Result.b := Values[2];
  Result.c := Values[3];
  Result.d := Values[4];
end;

function IndexOf(const Value: TValue): Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to high(Combinations) do
    if Combinations[Result] = Value then
      exit;
  raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Invalid value');
end;

procedure CheckCounts(const Name: string; const GetSample: TFunc<TValue>);
const
  N = 1000000;
var
  i: Integer;
  Counts: TArray<Integer>;
  Range: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Counts, Length(Combinations));
  for i := 1 to N do
    inc(Counts[IndexOf(GetSample)]);
  Range := MaxIntValue(Counts) - MinIntValue(Counts);
  Writeln(Name);
  Writeln(StringOfChar('-', Length(Name)));
  Writeln(Format('Range = %d, N = %d', [Range, N]));
  Writeln;
end;

begin
  Randomize;
  InitialiseCombinations;
  CheckCounts('Heffernan', GetSampleHeffernan);
  //CheckCounts('Van Dien', GetSampleVanDien);
  CheckCounts('Lama', GetSampleLama);
  Readln;
end.
```

The output, from one particular run, is:

```
Heffernan
---------
Range = 620, N = 1000000

Lama
----
Range = 200192, N = 1000000
```

The Van Dien variant is commented out at the moment since it produces invalid values.

---

OK, I debugged and fixed the Van Dien variant. The test and results now look like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Math,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TValue = record
    a, b, c, d: Integer;
    procedure Write;
    class operator Equal(const lhs, rhs: TValue): Boolean;
  end;

procedure TValue.Write;
begin
  Writeln(a, ' ', b, ' ', c, ' ', d);
end;

class operator TValue.Equal(const lhs, rhs: TValue): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (lhs.a=rhs.a) and (lhs.b=rhs.b) and (lhs.c=rhs.c) and (lhs.d=rhs.d);
end;

var
  Combinations: TArray<TValue>;

procedure InitialiseCombinations;
var
  a, b, c, d: Integer;
  Value: TValue;
  List: TList<TValue>;
begin
  List := TList<TValue>.Create;
  try
    for a := 2 to 7 do
      for b := 2 to 7 do
        for c := 2 to 7 do
        begin
          d := 22 - a - b - c;
          if InRange(d, 2, 7) then
          begin
            Value.a := a;
            Value.b := b;
            Value.c := c;
            Value.d := d;
            List.Add(Value);
          end;
        end;
    Combinations := List.ToArray;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetSampleHeffernan: TValue;
begin
  Result := Combinations[Random(Length(Combinations))];
end;

function GetSampleVanDien: TValue;
const
  TOTAL = 22;
  VALUE_COUNT = 4;
  MIN_VALUE = 2;
  MAX_VALUE = 7;
var
  Values: array[0..VALUE_COUNT-1] of Integer;
  Shortage: Integer;
  Candidates: TList<Integer>;
  ValueIndex: Integer;
  CandidateIndex: Integer;
begin
  Assert(VALUE_COUNT * MAX_VALUE >= TOTAL, 'Total can never be reached!');
  Assert(VALUE_COUNT * MIN_VALUE <= TOTAL, 'Total is always exceeded!');
  Candidates := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    for ValueIndex := 0 to VALUE_COUNT-1 do
    begin
      Values[ValueIndex] := MIN_VALUE;
      Candidates.Add(ValueIndex);
    end;
    Shortage := TOTAL - VALUE_COUNT * MIN_VALUE;
    while Shortage > 0 do
    begin
      CandidateIndex := Random(Candidates.Count);
      ValueIndex := Candidates[CandidateIndex];
      inc(Values[ValueIndex]);
      if Values[ValueIndex] = MAX_VALUE then
        Candidates.Delete(CandidateIndex);
      dec(Shortage);
    end;
  finally
    Candidates.Free;
  end;

  Result.a := Values[0];
  Result.b := Values[1];
  Result.c := Values[2];
  Result.d := Values[3];
end;

function GetSampleLama: TValue;
type
  TRandomValues = array[1..4] of Integer;
var
  IntSum: Integer;
  Values: TRandomValues;
begin
  // initialize a helper variable for calculating sum of the generated numbers
  IntSum := 0;
  // in the first step just generate a number in the range of 2 to 7 and store
  // it to the first integer element
  Values[1] := RandomRange(2, 7);
  // and increment the sum value
  IntSum := IntSum + Values[1];
  // as the next step we need to generate number, but here we need also say in
  // which range by the following rules to ensure we ever reach 22 (consider, if
  // the 1st number was e.g. 3, then you can't generate the second number smaller
  // than 5 because then even if the next two numbers would be max, you would get
  // e.g. only 3 + 4 + 7 + 7 = 21, so just use this rule:
  // Values[1] Values[2]
  //        2      6..7
  //        3      5..7
  //        4      4..7
  //        5      3..7
  //     6..7      2..7
  Values[2] := RandomRange(Max(2, 8 - Values[1]), 7);
  // and increment the sum value
  IntSum := IntSum + Values[2];
  // if the third step we need to generate a value in the range of 15 to 20 since
  // the fourth number can be still in the range of 2 to 7 which means that the sum
  // after this step must be from 22-7 to 22-2 which is 15 to 20, so let's generate
  // a number which will fit into this sum
  Values[3] := RandomRange(Max(2, Min(7, 15 - IntSum)), Max(2, Min(7, 20 - IntSum)));
  // and for the last number let's just take 22 and subtract the sum of all previous
  // numbers
  Values[4] := 22 - (IntSum + Values[3]);

  Result.a := Values[1];
  Result.b := Values[2];
  Result.c := Values[3];
  Result.d := Values[4];
end;

function IndexOf(const Value: TValue): Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to high(Combinations) do
    if Combinations[Result] = Value then
      exit;
  raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Invalid value');
end;

procedure CheckCounts(const Name: string; const GetSample: TFunc<TValue>);
const
  N = 1000000;
var
  i: Integer;
  Counts: TArray<Integer>;
  Range: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Counts, Length(Combinations));
  for i := 1 to N do
    inc(Counts[IndexOf(GetSample)]);
  Range := MaxIntValue(Counts) - MinIntValue(Counts);
  Writeln(Name);
  Writeln(StringOfChar('-', Length(Name)));
  Writeln(Format('Range = %d, N = %d', [Range, N]));
  Writeln;
end;

begin
  Randomize;
  InitialiseCombinations;
  CheckCounts('Heffernan', GetSampleHeffernan);
  CheckCounts('Van Dien', GetSampleVanDien);
  CheckCounts('Lama', GetSampleLama);
  Readln;
end.
```

```
Heffernan
---------
Range = 599, N = 1000000

Van Dien
--------
Range = 19443, N = 1000000

Lama
----
Range = 199739, N = 1000000
```

---

And just to ram it home, here are some plots of empirical probability mass function of the various distributions:

[image]

---

OK, now I fixed @TLama's code. It was using [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) incorrectly. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) states:

> RandomRange returns a random integer from the range that extends between AFrom and ATo (non-inclusive).

The key is that the range is defined as a closed-open interval. The value returned is in the range [AFrom..ATo), or expressed with inequality signs, AFrom <= Value < ATo.

But @TLama's code is written on the assumption that the interval is closed at both ends. So the code can readily be fixed by adding 1 to the second parameter of each call to `RandomRange`. When we do that the output looks like this:

```
Heffernan
---------
Range = 587, N = 1000000

Van Dien
--------
Range = 19425, N = 1000000

Lama
----
Range = 79320, N = 1000000
```

And the empircal PMF plot becomes:

[image]

---

The bottom line in all this is that sampling is difficult to get right if you care about the distribution.

Comment: I would love to see some code for this. Not that I don't think it would work. But not sure. U said check if ladt number is in range?

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: Just the idea. Why are you checking if last number is in range?

Comment: My outline has 3 nested loops. Final number selected by sum = 22 constraint. Must then verify that number in range 2-7. Or do it with 4 for loops and check that sum = 22. Whichever you prefer.

Comment: The point is that the 22 constraint makes the final loop spurious

Comment: There's 80 possibilities as it turns out. Of course it's a fine option to generate and store those somewhere, to be selected from randomly.

Comment: I get it. Took me a min.  But not sure I want to niw solve easy way to get all the sets.

Comment: Umm lots of data there. But maybe I don't see it.  But are u saying yours is more random? Or more evenly random?  Btw very nice job

Comment: All these algos are equally random. Only mine samples from a uniform distribution.

Comment: ok trying to get this to work, but i dont understand it all. How do i call this? and how do i view the result?

Comment: You only need the code from the first program in my answer. Call `InitialiseCombinations` once at startup. Declare `Combinations` as a global somewhere in your program. Then call `GetSample` every time you need to take a sample.

Comment: ok , i get it now all good there..i did notice your using writeln and readln i assume you where writeing the number to a text file or something?  instead of writeing them i want to assign the value to a lable.  So in the write procedure i would just say label1 := inttostr(a) ...(b)  ect.. correct?

Comment: You can do whatever you like with the values. They come out of `GetSample` and after that it's entirely up to you.

Comment: +1 working great!  thanks again.  At first i thought this question was going to get alot of down votes.. turned out to give alot of great answers and information :D

Comment: Glen, there are only two answers (so far) that produce a uniform output. Mine and @kobik's comment (now deleted) to the Q.

Comment: what if there was a bigger range say 1-12.. and a total of 42. would it still be as good?

Comment: for loop to build combinations runs 12*12*12 times. But only a very small number of those are valid. 42 is large total. For instance 1-5 are invalid. Number of cards is key. The problem becomes harder with more cards. When it becomes harder you'd use rejection sampling as per my other answer. But I'm sure I answered the question you asked!!

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: this solution has been proven non-uniform by @DavidHeffernan.**

22 is quite a low number, so the following should work reasonably well:

```
procedure ShowValues;
const
  TOTAL = 22;
  VALUE_COUNT = 4;
  MIN_VALUE = 2;
  MAX_VALUE = 7;
var
  Values: array[0..VALUE_COUNT-1] of Integer;
  Shortage: Integer;
  Candidates: TList<Integer>;
  ValueIndex: Integer;
  CandidateIndex: Integer;
begin
  Assert(VALUE_COUNT * MAX_VALUE >= TOTAL, 'Total can never be reached!');
  Assert(VALUE_COUNT * MIN_VALUE <= TOTAL, 'Total is always exceeded!');
  Candidates := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    for ValueIndex := 0 to VALUE_COUNT-1 do
    begin
      Values[ValueIndex] := MIN_VALUE;
      Candidates.Add(ValueIndex);
    end;
    Shortage := TOTAL - VALUE_COUNT * MIN_VALUE;
    while Shortage > 0 do
    begin
      CandidateIndex := Random(Candidates.Count);
      ValueIndex := Candidates[CandidateIndex];
      inc(Values[ValueIndex]);
      if Values[ValueIndex] = MAX_VALUE then
        Candidates.Delete(CandidateIndex);
      dec(Shortage);
    end;
  finally
    Candidates.Free;
  end;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Values[0]) + ' ' + IntToStr(Values[1]) + 
    ' ' + IntToStr(Values[2]) + ' ' + IntToStr(Values[3]));
end;
```

All four numbers are initialized to the minimum value. Then, while we have not reached the total, we randomly select one of the numbers that may still be increased and increase it by one.

Comment: What distribution will this have?

Comment: That is another good way to think about it. Never thought of adding a 1 to one of the four sets till 22 is reached

Comment: It's just hard to analyse. Because of the complexity. Why would you choose complex and slow over simple?

Comment: No, it's not down to the RNG. It's the algo. These combinatorial algorithms can be hard to get right. Take a look at my latest update, especially the plots.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thinking about this a bit more, I suppose it's that distributing one by one randomly makes it more likely that we distribute evenly and therefore (5, 6, 5, 6) is more likely than (7, 7, 4, 4).

Comment: This is what I meant by complexity. The code and the algorithm are simple to implement. But not-trivial to reason about.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Point taken. :)

Answer (score 2):

An efficient alternative, that does not involve constructing a table of all possible samples, is as follows:

1. Choose three values in the range [2..7].
2. Set the fourth value to be equal to 22 less the sum of the first three.
3. If the fourth value is not in the range [2..7], goto 1.
4. Return the four values.

The coding is simple, and uses the same structure as my first answer:

```
function GetSample: TValue;
begin
  repeat
    Result.a := RandomRange(2, 8);
    Result.b := RandomRange(2, 8);
    Result.c := RandomRange(2, 8);
    Result.d := 22 - Result.a - Result.b- Result.c;
  until InRange(Result.d, 2, 7);
end;
```

The empirical probability mass, using the same test harness as my first answer, looks like this:

[image]

Comment: **Theoretically**, this could be an endless loop. What do you think? (Wasn't that what @TLama first suggested - with the comment I added?).

Comment: @kobik Only if your RNG is no good. Rejection sampling is a bread and butter technique in statistical computing. I thought it was you that suggested this in comments. It's a solid technique that should be represented here.

Comment: @kobik RNG is random number generator. Any good RNG cannot fail to cover the space.

Comment: Yes, I suggested that in my comment. but I was not sure if it was efficient (I thought that in theory it could result an endless loop, or at least way too many loops) - That's why I deleted it (plus as per @TLama's request). Thanks for clearing this :)

Comment: @kobik It's reasonably efficient. You'll reject 136 out of 216 on average. Cannot beat the approach in my other answer which has a single call to the RNG per sample.